# Group and sum list (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I've got a list of objects

```
    Class Bundledtellingen
        Property tTimestamp As String
        Property tValue As Double
    End Class
```

Now I am trying to group this list by tTimestamp and sum tValue. By searching similar questions it was clear the best way to go is using Linq. I've put this together:

```
    Dim query = bundledlist.GroupBy( _
    Function(telling) telling.tTimestamp, _
    Function(telling) telling.tTimestamp, _
    Function(ts, values) New With _
        {.Key = ts, _
        .Sum = values.Sum()} _
    )

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\test.txt")
        For Each result In query
            writer.WriteLine(result.Key & " " & result.Sum)
        Next
    End Using
```

As far as I can tell by looking at the examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493.aspx#Y0 this should work, though i get the following exception: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' accepts this number of arguments."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified one unnecessary parameter into your `GroupBy` call. Thy that one:

```
Dim query = bundledlist.GroupBy( _
                Function(telling) telling.tTimestamp, _
                Function(ts, values) New With _
                    {.Key = ts, _
                    .Sum = values.Sum()} _
                )
```

The first one is key selector, the second is result selector.

Your call with 3 parameters has additional value selector, where you're selecting `Function(telling) telling.tTimestamp` twice - once for `Key` and once for `Value`. That's why your `Sum` didn't work: you tried call `Sum` on `telling.tTimestamp`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I only had to replace the second telling.tTimestamp with telling.tValue.